# How to make secondary labels in matplotlib chat?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I need add secondary label to my y axios in matplotlib chat.

[image]

Comment: Please go through the intro [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand the community expectations and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please take a look at the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/15497888).

Comment: StackOverflow is a place you to share _your_ code at let us help you with where you're struggling. StackOverflow (generally) is not a forum where we provide you with complete working examples on a given topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sample code I used already.

```
    def annotate_yrange(self, ymin, ymax,
                        label=None, fontsize=12,
                        offset=-0.1,
                        width=-0.1,
                        text_kwargs={'rotation': 'horizontal'},
                        ax=None,
                        patch_kwargs={'facecolor': 'white'},
                        line_kwargs={'color': 'black'},

                        ):
        if ax is None:
            ax = plt.gca()

        trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(
            ax.transAxes, ax.transData)

        rect = Rectangle((offset, ymin), width=width, height=ymax -
                         ymin, transform=trans, clip_on=False, **patch_kwargs)
        ax.add_patch(rect)

        min_delimiter = Line2D((offset+width, offset), (ymin, ymin),
                               transform=trans, clip_on=False, **line_kwargs, linewidth=.7)
        max_delimiter = Line2D((offset+width, offset), (ymax, ymax),
                               transform=trans, clip_on=False, **line_kwargs, linewidth=.7)
        mid_delimiter = Line2D((offset+width, offset + width), (ymin, ymax),
                               transform=trans, clip_on=False, **line_kwargs, linewidth=.7)
        ax.add_artist(min_delimiter)
        ax.add_artist(max_delimiter)
        ax.add_artist(mid_delimiter)

        # label
        if label:
            x = offset + 0.5 * width
            y = ymin + 0.5 * (ymax - ymin)
            ax.text(x, y, label, fontsize=fontsize, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',
                    clip_on=False, transform=trans, **text_kwargs)  
.........


width = -0.12
offsets = [0, -0.12]
for ii, (level, offset) in enumerate(zip((labelPos, mlabelPos), offsets)):
     for jj, (ymin, ymax) in enumerate(level):
           if ii == 0:
                temp_labels[jj] = '\n'.join(temp_labels[jj][i:i+17]
                                for i in range(0, len(temp_labels[jj]), 17))  
                self.annotate_yrange(ymin, ymax,  temp_labels[jj], fontsize=10, offset=offset, width=width, text_kwargs={'rotation': 0}) 
            else:
                temp_mlabels[jj] = '\n'.join(temp_mlabels[jj][i:i+17]
                               for i in range(0, len(temp_mlabels[jj]), 17)) 
                self.annotate_yrange(ymin, ymax,  temp_mlabels[jj], fontsize=10, offset=offset, width=width, text_kwargs={'rotation': 0})
```